# Show an XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I got an XMLDocument in my Doc variable,
I need to show it to the user.

```
 XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
 Doc.LoadXml(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString())
```

Is there a function like Doc.show() or something like this?

Comment: How are you looking to display the XML? Are you using WinForms, WPF, Console application? etc.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there's not.  `XmlDocument` has nothing to do with your presentation layer.  Pick your favorite presentation technology (WPF, WinForms, web...town crier, whatever) and render it accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Down voter didn't like my joke I guess :)

Comment: Is that you in the pic??  :p

Answer (score 0):

You can display the XML of the XMLDocument object, for instance, by setting a MultiLine TextBox's Text property using the OuterXML property of the XMLDocument object.

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"C:\path\to\xmlFile.xml");

// For display on the console...
Console.WriteLine("XML: " + xmlDocument.OuterXML);

// For display in a WinForms TextBox control...
var text = new TextBox();
text.MultiLine = true;
text.Text = xmlDocument.OuterXML;
```

You can, of course, use a different control or presentation layer technology of your choice to render the XML content, but I've given this WinForms TextBox control example merely for illustrative purposes.